# Problem with Crawl on ONE WebApplication in our SharePoint 2016 OnPrem solution - Access Denied

Tags: search, 2016, access-denied, crawl

We have problem with Search/Crawl on only one of the Web Applications in our SharePoint 2016 OnPremise. We get the error message, Access Denied in Crawl Log.  As we know of we have set the Crawl account correct on the Search Application and as Full Read on the Web Application.
As we can see we have the same settings for the other Web Applications were the Crawl works and gives result.

Search Service Application: Search Administration Default content access account is also set on

- Administrator for Search Service Application - Full Control and Read (In Service Application - Search)
- Search Crawling Account in Policy for Web Application (In Manage Web application in Central Administraton)
  [image: See Picture]

Thanks for helping out since we are out of good ideas

Comment: From the faulting web application - can you try to remove and reset the same permissions once more? Have you also tried signing in with the crawl account to see if the permission actually works?

Comment: Thanks Christoffer for you respons. Not sure if this should be added as a comment or a new post in this but I go for the comment.
I have removed the permissions on the web application, deleted the crawl account and added it again.
Where do you mean that I would try to sign in with the crawl account?

Comment: If you sign in with the crawl account and try to access a site on the web application that failing you could either see that the account can access the content or you would get access denied to sort that out.

Comment: Did sign in on the site with the Crawl account and could access the site and stuff on it.

Comment: If you were to add the webapplication to it's own content source and try to start a full crawl to see if you can trigger/catch any errors in event viewer or the ULS logs?

Comment: Yeah, it is better to logon to that site using crawl account, from the server itself - where crawl process is running, and download any document from that site.

Comment: Thanks for you help.
I signed in to the server with the Crawl account and tried to access one of the sites where crawl works and signed in without any problems.
With the web application with Crawl issues I continuesly get requested for sign in. ^
Checked again on the Web Applications the User Profile and on both the Crawl account have Full Read.